# IBM Domino Designer JavaScript editor lags in virtual environment

Tags: domino-designer-eclipse

I have installed Domino Designer in a Windows VM on VirtualBox on OS X.

When I start entering code in the JavaScript editor, Domino starts to work for every letter I type. The hourglass icon appears and the network symbol on the status bar flashes. This operation takes up to several seconds for every letter I type.

If I try to type anything before the hourglass disappears, the keyboard may hang up and the result is a long list of the same letters that I have to delete again (causing the hourglass to appear for each letter I delete again).

I have tried to disable functionality like "Content Assist", "Quick Diff" and other helpful stuff without luck.

I would really appreciate hints or tips to make this nightmare vanish...

Comment: I am running Domino Release 9.0.1FP5 SHF106 on Windows 10 64 bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Joel for leading me into the right path.

I did several things, and together it now seems that I have a much better environment. I still see the hour glass from time to time, but it does not mess up my code anymore, and most of the time it does not bother me.

What I did was the following:

Changed the memory settings for Domino in this file:

[notes dir]\framework\rcp\deploy\jvm.properties

New values:

vmarg.Xmx=-Xmx1024m

vmarg.Xms=-Xms512m

vmarg.Xmca=-Xmca512k

Then I changed the virtual memory of my guest Windows install to a fixed swap file of 4096 MB.

At least I connected my Mac to a faster network using Thunderbolt to Ethernet cable adapter. I don't think the last thing did any difference, but at least I now have a faster and more reliable network connection.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used domino designer, but first thought would be that your VM isn't handling the processing required by the designer.
What are the specs on you windows VM? Did you allocate enough RAM, for example? Make sure they match the requirements to run the designer:
http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=1351628933716&osPlatform=Windows

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11107222)

Comment: Did you read the "answer" I made OhBeWise? Or just comment on there being a link? I tried to change my answer to a comment after I posted, but the system was too involved to bother. The link in this case is NOT the answer, just helpful info. Perhaps you should think before making pointless comments.

Comment: Your post was marked as low quality and sent to review. I do not argue that your inquiries led the author in the right direction and was therefore useful. That said, it is policy of SO to have answers be stand alone with links merely as support. And users are encouraged to find ways of earning Rep in order to unlock comments. I was merely doing my job in the Review queue - no need for hostility.